# Get color of the first pixel of an image on Windows Phone

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I'm using the following code to get the color of the first pixel of an image

```
var wb = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)Image.Source);
int pixelxy = wb.Pixels[0];
```

Now I'm getting the result -10975 in pixelxy. How can I convert this value to a color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the color of the first pixel I would recommend that you use:

```
Color c = wb.GetPixel(0, 0);
```

If you really want to use the Pixel array and convert yourself, you can check how the GetPixel function does it, as it is open source (see [WriteableBitmapBaseExtensions.cs at Codeplex](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#trunk/Source/WriteableBitmapEx/WriteableBitmapBaseExtensions.cs)), by just changing how you get the c value you get this, which should do the trick:

```
var c = wb.Pixels[0];
var a = (byte)(c >> 24);


// Prevent division by zero
int ai = a;
if (ai == 0)
{
   ai = 1;
}

// Scale inverse alpha to use cheap integer mul bit shift
ai = ((255 << 8) / ai);
Color theColor = Color.FromArgb(a,
                 (byte)((((c >> 16) & 0xFF) * ai) >> 8),
                 (byte)((((c >> 8) & 0xFF) * ai) >> 8),
                 (byte)((((c & 0xFF) * ai) >> 8)));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
Color color = bitmap.GetPixel(0,0);
```